# Visual Studio warns me about some invalid html attributes

Tags: html, visual-studio

I have a list of items in an html table. On each row (tr) I'm proceeding like this:

```
<tr idAffaire="@suite.IdAffaire" idSuite="@suite.IdSuite" class="@suite.Username row droppable">
```

I used the attributes **idAffaire** and **idSuite** for retrieving some infos later. I know the official identification attribute is "id" but in my case I need 2 id. When I compile my code, VS is warning me about some things:

- this name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed.
- attribute 'idaffaire' is not a valid attribute of element 'tr'
- ...

Is it possible to prevent these warnings? Is there a better way of doing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an HTML5 doctype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing invalid HTML. As you mentioned, `id` is a valid attribute but `idAffaire` or `idSuite` are not. I'm assuming from the fact that you get a warning about uppercase characters, you are using an XHTML doctype. A better way to do this would be to use an HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And use custom data attributes for your new attributes:

```
<tr data-affaire="@suite.IdAffaire" data-suite="@suite.IdSuite" class="@suite.Username row droppable">
```

Comment: I already use <!DOCTYPE html> and VS still warns me... Next, I try using data-affaire="...." but I still get warnings about invalid attribute element. I would like a solution where I have no warnings :)

Comment: In that case, I think you'll just have to turn off validation! I just read that even if VS is set to validate against HTML5 (to check if it is, see Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation) that it won't validate custom `data` attributes, so you'll get warnings with my example anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation > [Untick] Show errors

Ideally, you could use 2 hidden input fields with the id="suite" and value="whatever" to allow you to pick these up in a valid way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add name space extension of yours. Then define your newly introduced attributes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is termed as adding custom attributes to html elements, which have a very varying opinion among the experts.

Firstly , using capital in html attributes is not recommended, you can switch to small case.
Secondly  , adding custom attributes in XHTML (which i suppose you are using) throws warning, where as this is perfectly valid in HTML5.

there are few option to deal with it -

use Jquery .data() api to store data with java script.
or
follow a specific convention while storing data making it easy to maintain and read.You can follow HTML5 syntax

```
   <ul>
       <li data-id='5' data-name='john'></li>
   </ul>
```